# How to know the IAM user who created a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have an AWS account with an IAM group, this group contains practically 6 users and most operations in the account are done by this 6 users.

There are 12 Lambda Functions that have been created in the account and there is a particular lambda function (created by one of the 6 users) that I am trying to know who created it (The Lambda function owner).

Please is there a way to do this ?

Comment: If you have cloudtrail enabled, this info will be in your cloudtrail logs.

Comment: Have you tried asking which of the six users created it?

Comment: The Lambda functions were created at a time when CloudTrail was not yet configured i the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources created in AWS Accounts are associated with the **Account**, not the IAM User that created the account.

When a user requests AWS to create resources, IAM verifies that the user has permission to create resources. If so, then the resources are created in the Account, but no relationship with the user is kept on that resource.

You can, however, use **AWS CloudTrail** to view information about the API request that created the resource.

From [What Is AWS CloudTrail? - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html):

> AWS CloudTrail is an AWS service that helps you enable governance, compliance, and operational and risk auditing of your AWS account. Actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service are recorded as events in CloudTrail. Events include actions taken in the AWS Management Console, AWS Command Line Interface, and AWS SDKs and APIs.